# Eclipse - Limit logcat output to debug relevent logs

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I reinstalled my Eclipse and now my `Logcat` logs everything my phone sends like battery status or mail sending status.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse/Logcat to just log what is really coming from my app which I'm debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the Logcat with "app:com.yourdomain.appname".  I've also added a filter that gets rid of more items using a not operator:

```
tag:^((?!CoreMetrics|InputEventConsistency|memalloc|Adreno200-EGLSUB|Resources|global|TaggingRequest|Facade[B|U]|dalvik|skia|KeyCharacterMap|BackStackEntry|FragmentManager|ServiceRunnable|ServiceLocator|BaseHttpRequest|szipinf|APACHE).)*$
```

You'll need to edit the list specifically for the items you're seeing, but it's a great way to reduce the static.

Answer (score 1):

You can log using a Tag and then filter in logcat using the same tag. You can add a filter by clicking on the + in the left hand side list. You can recognize it because the first tag will be "All Messages". Clicking through the list enables the filters.

```
Log.i("MyTag", "some log message");
```

Also in newer versions of the ADT eclipse plugin, I blieve that it auto-adds your app to the filter list.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter search filters in the search box at the top, or you can make those filters permanent via the filters panel visible on left side of eclipse logcat window.  If it is not visible then note the button on the top right of logcat that displays/hides it.

"Is there a way to tell Eclipse/Logcat to just log what is really coming from my app which I'm debugging?"

Not exactly.  You should be able to do that with the filter "app:com.yourapp".  This filters based on the 'application' column/data of the logcat output, which would be perfect but Android devices are rather eratic at adding that information to debug output. Actually, the Nexus 4 is the first phone I've used that reliably specifies that data field in its logcat output.

But even if 'application' column doesn't work for you, you should be able to find other filters that reduce the visible log statements to a manageable level.

Answer (score 0):

In Your LogCat click button(Second Last) to left of the "downarrow button" the click "plus" sign write filter name and in application  write the package name of the app you wanna get filtered logs for examole com.yourapp press ok and viola !!!